# Combining IF statements and match statements in google sheets

Tags: excel, if-statement, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

## Cheltenham spreadsheet

### Context

The purpose of the below spreadsheet is to calculate the amount of points gamblers are making over cheltenham.

Each participant picks one horse a day for every race.

- If there horse finishes 1st they get 5 points
- 2nd 3 points
- 3rd 1 point

### Spreadsheet

| Name | Race 1 | Race 2 | Race 3 | Race 4 | Race 5 | Race 6 | Race 7 | Points |  | Race 1 results | Race 2 results | Race 3 results | Race 4 results | Race 5 results | Race 6 results | Race 7 results | Race 8 results |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Daniel | 1 | 5 | 17 | 24 | 3 | 2 | 8 | 1800 | 1st place | 2 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 2 | 12 | 2 | 7 |
| Bob | 2 | 23 | 5 | 2 | 24 | 4 | 1 |  | 2nd place | 3 | 5 | 5 | 2 | 24 | 3 | 3 | 6 |
| Mark | 6 | 5 | 7 | 5 | 1 | 7 | 3 |  | 3rd place | 1 | 4 | 12 | 3 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 5 |
| Luke | 8 | 4 | 9 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| etc |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

### Problem

I am trying to match the players guesses to the results inputted on the right so that I will get a total column calculating the points.

### Attempt

This is what I was trying but am not getting correct results as highlighted by first Points cell.

```
=IF(B2=K2,I2+5,If(B2=K3,I2+3,If(B2=K4,I2+1)))
```

### Microsoft excel

**Is there an easier way of doing this in excel?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each player and each course, try

```
=choose(iferror(MATCH(B2,K$2:K$4,0),0)+1,0,5,3,1)
```

then sum each row

[image]